# My pig dice game in JAVA won't save each player's score and the game doesn't stop even after reaching the score

Tags: java

My pig dice game for my computer science class won't save each individual score after each turn, and my game won't stop even after a player reaches the max score( I know boo leans are the cause but, I don't know what else to use). Also when a player declines to roll again the score goes back to zero. If anyone help me with this, it would be really nice!! Thank youu.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class PigDiceGamebyJian {

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static Random gen = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //char repeat;

        System.out.println(" Welcome to the Pig Dice Game ");

        System.out.println("This game requires two players");

        System.out.println("How to play: each player will take turn rolling the dice (adding up the turns) until the sum is 30");

        System.out.println("First one to get to  30 wins, though if on a turn, if you roll a 1, ");

        System.out.println("you will give the dice to the other player, and you will not add anything to your score because 1 = 0");

        System.out.println("Enough with the boring rules.");

        String p1 = getName();

        String p2 = getName();

        System.out.println("Hello " + p1 + " and " + p2 + ".");

        System.out.println("Please enter a score that you would like to play up to");

        final int fin = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println(p1 + " will be going first.");

        int p1score = roll(p1, 0, fin);

        int p2score = roll(p2, 0, fin);

        while (p1score < fin && p2score < fin ) {

            p1score += roll(p1, 0, fin);

            p2score += roll(p2, 0, fin);

        }

    }

    private static int roll(String player, int score, int fin) {

        boolean go = true;

        int counter = 0;

        while(go) {

            int dice =  gen.nextInt(6) + 1;



            if (dice == 1) {

                System.out.println(player + " You rolled 1, your turn is over.");

                System.out.println(player + " your total is " + counter);

                return 0;

            }


            System.out.println(player  + " you rolled a " + dice);


            counter = counter + dice;

            System.out.println(player + " Your turn score is " + counter + " Do you want to roll again? (y)es (n)o");

            String ans = sc.next();

            if (ans.equals("n")) {

                go = false;

                System.out.println(player + " your score is " + score);

                return score;


            }

            if (score >    fin) {

                go = false;

                System.out.println(player + " you've won the PIG DICE GAME!!");

            }


        }

         return score;
    }

    private static String getName() {

        System.out.println("Enter the name for a player.");

        String player = sc.next();

        return player;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger?

Comment: You add the `dice` to `counter`, and then return `score` (which is never modified) in your `roll` method.

Comment: Out of curiousity: are those blank lines between each statement intentional?

Comment: The blank lines in between help me separate each line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logical flaw in your program. You are calling your roll function with a score = 0 as your parameter.

```
    int p1score = roll(p1, 0, fin);

    int p2score = roll(p2, 0, fin);

    while (p1score < fin && p2score < fin ) {

        p1score += roll(p1, 0, fin);

        p2score += roll(p2, 0, fin);

    }
```

In your roll method, you either return 0 or you return score which is 0 everytime. So your p1score and p2score which is determinted based on what the roll function returns will both always forever be 0.

This is why your game doesn't stop because it is stuck in the while loop.

You need to change the roll function to return the score + the value that you have rolled.